# Headers with FastAPI

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi

I created an endpoint which requires the User Agent as described in the documentation:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/header-params/#__tabbed_2_1

However, the Swagger documentation generated displays it as a query param.

[image]

Any ideas of what is wrong in my setup?

```
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import FastAPI, Header

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(user_agent: Annotated[str | None, Header()] = None):
    return {"User-Agent": user_agent}
```

I am running it with Python 3.10.

Comment: Have you tried the `Python 3.10+ non-Annotated` version?

Comment: It works well in the non-Annotated version.

Comment: What versions of python and fastapi are you running? The `Annotated` version was just launched a couple days ago in version 0.95.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of fastapi are you running? I found the same issue when running fastapi 0.94.1

Basically, fastapi <0.95 does not support Annotated. It will always interpret Annotated as a query parameter. The problem is: it won't throw an error because it is still valid.

You have two options: upgrade fastapi to >=0.95 or use the non-annotated version

```
@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(user_agent: str | None = Header(default=None)):
    return {"User-Agent": user_agent}
```